# Migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL on Linux (Kubuntu)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration

## A long time ago on a system far, far away...

Trying to migrate a database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. All the documentation I have read covers, in great detail, how to migrate the structure. I have found very little documentation on migrating the data. The schema has 13 tables (which have been migrated successfully) and 9 GB of data.

MySQL version: 5.1.x
PostgreSQL version: 8.4.x

I want to use the R programming language to analyze the data using SQL select statements; PostgreSQL has PL/R, but MySQL has nothing (as far as I can tell).

## A New Hope

Create the database location (`/var` has insufficient space; also dislike having the PostgreSQL version number everywhere -- upgrading would break scripts!):

1. `sudo mkdir -p /home/postgres/main`
2. `sudo cp -Rp /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main /home/postgres`
3. `sudo chown -R postgres.postgres /home/postgres`
4. `sudo chmod -R 700 /home/postgres`
5. `sudo usermod -d /home/postgres/ postgres`

All good to here. Next, restart the server and configure the database using these [installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL):

1. `sudo apt-get install postgresql pgadmin3`
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 stop`
3. `sudo vi /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf`
4. Change `data_directory` to `/home/postgres/main`
5. `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 start`
6. `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`
7. `\password postgres`
8. `sudo -u postgres createdb climate`
9. `pgadmin3`

Use `pgadmin3` to configure the database and create a schema.

The episode continues in a remote shell known as `bash`, with both databases running, and the installation of a set of tools with a rather unusual logo: [SQL Fairy](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/).

1. `perl Makefile.PL`
2. `sudo make install`
3. `sudo apt-get install perl-doc` (strangely, it is not called `perldoc`)
4. `perldoc SQL::Translator::Manual`

Extract a PostgreSQL-friendly DDL and all the `MySQL` data:

1. `sqlt -f DBI --dsn dbi:mysql:climate --db-user user --db-password password -t PostgreSQL > climate-pg-ddl.sql`
2. Edit `climate-pg-ddl.sql` and convert the identifiers to lowercase, and insert the schema reference (using VIM):

   - `:%s/"\([A-Z_]*\)"/\L\1/g`
   - `:%s/ TABLE / TABLE climate./g`
   - `:%s/ on / on climate./g`
3. `mysqldump --skip-add-locks --complete-insert --no-create-db --no-create-info --quick --result-file="climate-my.sql" --databases climate --skip-comments -u root -p`

It might be worthwhile to simply rename the tables and columns in MySQL to lowercase:

1. `select concat( 'RENAME TABLE climate.', TABLE_NAME, ' to climate.', lower(TABLE_NAME), ';' ) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='climate';`
2. Execute the commands from the previous step.
3. There is probably a way to do the same for columns; I changed them manually because it was faster than figuring out how to write the query.

## The Database Strikes Back

Recreate the structure in PostgreSQL as follows:

1. `pgadmin3` (switch to it)
2. Click the **Execute arbitrary SQL queries** icon
3. Open `climate-pg-ddl.sql`
4. Search for `TABLE "` replace with `TABLE climate."` (insert the schema name `climate`)
5. Search for `on "` replace with `on climate."` (insert the schema name `climate`)
6. Press `F5` to execute

This results in:

```
Query returned successfully with no result in 122 ms.
```

## Replies of the Jedi

At this point I am stumped.

- Where do I go from here (*what are the steps*) to convert `climate-my.sql` to `climate-pg.sql` so that they can be executed against PostgreSQL?
- How to I make sure the indexes are copied over correctly (to maintain referential integrity; I don't have constraints at the moment to ease the transition)?
- How do I ensure that adding new rows in PostgreSQL will start enumerating from the index of the last row inserted (and not conflict with an existing primary key from the sequence)?
- How do you ensure the schema name comes through when transforming the data from MySQL to PostgreSQL inserts?

#### Resources

A fair bit of information was needed to get this far:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL
- http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/site-mysql-postgresql-1
- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL
- http://pgfoundry.org/frs/shownotes.php?release_id=810
- http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for a good laugh @ the headings.

Comment: I'm sure you have good reasons for migrating to postgresql, but note that lack of a DB interface between MySQL and R needn't be one of them: check out http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/ (provided by the r-cran-rmysql package on Kubuntu).

Comment: pl/r is very very nice.  Generally speaking, the PL languages are almost worth the switch alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do for such migrations is two-fold:

- Extract the whole database definition from MySQL and adapt it to PostgreSQL syntax.
- Go over the database definition and transform it to take advantage of functionality in PostgreSQL that doesn't exist in MySQL.

Then do the conversion, and write a program in whatever language you are most comfortable with that accomplishes the following:

- Reads the data from the MySQL database.
- Performs whatever transformation is necessary on the data to be stored in the PostgreSQL database.
- Saves the now-transformed data in the PostgreSQL database.

**Redesign the tables for PostgreSQL to take advantage of its features.**

If you just do something like use a `sed` script to convert the SQL dump from one format to the next, all you are doing is putting a MySQL database in a PostgreSQL server.  You can do that, and there will still be some benefit from doing so, but if you're going to migrate, migrate fully.

It will involve a little bit more up-front time spent, but I have yet to come across a situation where it isn't worth it.

Comment: Well, that's the part that nobody can answer:  only you can, after you have redesigned the schema.  There is no generic means of doing it effectively which I am aware of.  You read your MySQL tables using the MySQL API libraries, and if you keep the tables exactly the same in pgsql, just write them as-is.  Or, if you alter the table/database structure to fit pg's capabilities, you transform it in memory and then write it.  But that's a data-specific problem.  You would do the same thing if you were going from MySQL to SQLite (which has fewer data types and less functionality, for example).

Comment: Anytime I migrate data from one RDBMS to the next (assuming I am familiar with both) I don't convert the dump to be compatible with the target.  In fact, I *never* take a dump that way, except to load it into an idle server.  Changing database servers is (rightly!) a fairly big deal, especially for applications which have complex data.

Answer (score 2):

#### Convert the mysqldump file to a PostgreSQL-friendly format

Convert the data as follows (do not use [mysql2pgsql.perl](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000198&release_id=810)):

1. Escape the quotes.

   `sed "s/\\\'/\'\'/g" climate-my.sql | sed "s/\\\r/\r/g" | sed "s/\\\n/\n/g" > escaped-my.sql`
2. Replace the `USE "climate";` with a search path and comment the comments:

   `sed "s/USE \"climate\";/SET search_path TO climate;/g" escaped-my.sql | sed "s/^\/\*/--/" > climate-pg.sql`
3. Connect to the database.

   `sudo su - postgres`
   `psql climate`
4. Set the encoding (mysqldump ignores its encoding parameter) and then execute the script.

   `\encoding iso-8859-1`
   `\i climate-pg.sql`

This series of steps will probably not work for complex databases with many mixed types. However, it works for `integer`s, `varchar`s, and `float`s.

#### Indexes, primary keys, and sequences

Since `mysqldump` included the primary keys when generating the `INSERT` statements, they will trump the table's automatic sequence. The sequences for all tables remained 1 upon inspection.

#### Set the sequence after import

Using the `ALTER SEQUENCE` command will set them to whatever value is needed.

#### Schema Prefix

There is no need to prefix tables with the schema name. Use:

```
SET search_path TO climate;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've converted a schema then migrating data would be the easy part:

- dump schema from PostgreSQL (you said that you've converted schema to postgres, so we will dump it for now, as we will be deleting and recreating target database, to have it cleaned):

  ```
  pg_dump dbname > /tmp/dbname-schema.sql
  ```
- split schema to 2 parts — `/tmp/dbname-schema-1.sql` containing create table statements, `/tmp/dbname-schema-2.sql` — the rest. PostgreSQL needs to import data before foreign keys, triggers etc. are imported, but after table definitions are imported.
- recreate database with only 1 part of schema:

  ```
  drop database dbname
  create database dbname
  \i /tmp/dbname-schema-1.sql
  -- now we have tables without data, triggers, foreign keys etc.
  ```
- import data:

  ```
  (
     echo 'start transaction';
     mysqldump --skip-quote-names dbname | grep ^INSERT;
     echo 'commit'
  ) | psql dbname
  -- now we have tables with data, but without triggers, foreign keys etc.
  ```

  A `--skip-quote-names` option is added in MySQL 5.1.3, so if you have older version, then install newer mysql temporarily in `/tmp/mysql` (`configure --prefix=/tmp/mysql && make install` should do) and use `/tmp/mysql/bin/mysqldump`.
- import the rest of schema:

  ```
  psql dbname
  start transaction
  \i /tmp/dbname-schema-2.sql
  commit
  -- we're done
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [etlalchemy](https://github.com/seanharr11/etlalchemy). It allows you migrate from **MySQL** to **PostgreSQL**, or between several other databases, in 4 lines of Python. You can read more about it [here](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/migrating-between-databases-with-etlalchemy).

To install: `pip install etlalchemy`

To run:

```py
from etlalchemy import ETLAlchemySource, ETLAlchemyTarget
# Migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL
src = ETLAlchemySource("mysql://user:passwd@hostname/dbname")
tgt = ETLAlchemyTarget("postgresql://user:passwd@hostname/dbname",
                          drop_database=True)
tgt.addSource(src)
tgt.migrate()
```