# Unique Constraint error creating tables in PostgreSQL (migrated from MySQL)

Tags: postgresql, unique, constraints, database-migration

I read with great enthusiasm the question entitled [Migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL on Linux (Kubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831009/migrate-from-mysql-to-postgresql-on-linux-kubuntu). The *Star Wars* theme made it that much more entertaining. But I've run into an issue regarding **Unique Constraints** in PostgreSQL.

I followed the above post closely to create a PostgreSQL DDL using [sqlt](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/). The thought process was to create the schema/tables first and then import the data. However 57 of my 72 tables use `CONSTRAINT "userid" UNIQUE ("user_id", "key")`

**Here is an example of one of the tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE "account_otherserviceinfo" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "user_id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "key" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "value" text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "user_id" UNIQUE ("user_id", "key")
);
```

When I copy these tables into my PostgreSQL DB using the Query tool in pgadmin3, I get the following error:

ERROR: relation "user_id" already exists
SQL state: 42P07

I did not design this database schema. I am only helping with the migration process. When reading the documentation on Unique Constraints, it appears that it is Ok to use the same name as long as it's in a different table. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-constraints.html. Am I misinterpreting this?

Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

PS: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/59087/dave-jarvis and https://stackoverflow.com/users/26534/michael-trausch for getting me this far ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> When reading the documentation on
>   Unique Constraints, it appears that it
>   is Ok to use the same name as long as
>   it's in a different table.

I'm not sure what part of the documentation you're reading, but you're misinterpreting it. Constraint names have to be globally unique. So you can have as many of these `UNIQUE ("user_id", "key")` as you like, but you can't name every one of them `"user_id"`.

Comment: Thanks Catcall. I am new to PostgreSQL. Coming from mySQL where this constraint is not applicable.

Comment: To be more precise, constraint name has to be unique in the schema

Answer (score 3):

You can get around this type of issue by giving your constraints more detailed names.

You will need to come up with a naming standard for you database objects to avoid this type of issue. Maybe something like type_schema_tablename_columnname.  So for example uidx_public_account_otherserviceinfor_user_id_key. That type of name will make sure you don't have issues and makes it easy to figure out what object an error message is referring to.  You can debate the clearest way to implement what I said, but the key point is come up with a standard to use for all objects that works for your enviroment.

Comment: This is a great suggestion StarShip3000. I decided to actually rebuild the tables using django-admin.py syncdb. This allowed me to test PostreSQL on my dev machine. I do have a live site [dzinebox](http://dzinebox.com) running mySQL. At some point I will have to do a data migration and will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `user_id` as constraint name because it is already used as column name.