# Mysql to Posgresql query conversion

Tags: postgresql

Please help to create postgresql query equal to mysql query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE newtable  TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent feature in PostgreSQL - at least in the current 9.3 or any prior version.

You must do this in a few steps:

- `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`
- `COPY` into the temp table
- Do an `UPDATE ... FROM` followed by an `INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` to merge data
- `DROP` the temp table

Search for "postgresql bulk upsert" or "postgresql copy upsert".

Comment: Can you show me exact query in step3
Do an UPDATE ... FROM followed by an INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...) to merge data

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for [COPY](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY)

COPY will be run by the PostgreSQL backend (user "postgres"). The backend user requires permissions to read & write to the data file in order to copy from/to it. You need to use an absolute pathname with COPY. \COPY on the other hand, runs under the current $USER, and with that users environment. And \COPY can handle relative pathnames. The psql \COPY is accordingly much easier to use if it handles what you need.

Comment: You're right. Replace is not there in postgresql copy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/772196/1029330